# De archivo excel a archivo CSV en pycharm

Tags: python, csv, pycharm

Hola implemento este codigo que tiene un archivo CSV que lo transferí de excel que contiene una tabla de datos  :

```
import csv

with open("Copia de servicio_agua.csv") as archivo_csv:
    archivo = csv.reader(archivo_csv, delimiter=",")
    contador_linea = 0
    for fila in archivo:
        if contador_linea == 0:
            print("Las columnas son ", fila[0], fila[1], fila[2])
        else:
            print(fila[0] + " trabaja en " + fila[1] + " y nacio en " + fila[2])
        contador_linea += 1
    print("Lineas procesadas: ", contador_linea)
```

y me aparece esto:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/manu/Desktop/ICC/PROYECTO 03/WGRGDGB.py", line 6, in <module>
    for fila in archivo:
  File "C:\Users\manu\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python37\lib\encodings\cp1252.py", line 23, in decode
    return codecs.charmap_decode(input,self.errors,decoding_table)[0]
UnicodeDecodeError: 'charmap' codec can't decode byte 0x81 in position 85: character maps to <undefined>
```

me podrían decir cual es error por favor?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probablemente tengas alguna tilde o caracter especial que no tome el encode que tiene por default el `open()` de python y eso hace que tengas un error en el csv reader.

Proba agregando esto a la linea del `with open(...)`:

```
with open("Copia de servicio_agua.csv", encoding='utf8') as archivo_csv:
```

Espero que te haya servido!